# $.post is not working in blackberry5

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, blackberry, jquery-mobile, blackberry-webworks

post method to send data to server.

```
function testing()
{


alert("###@@@@#############");
var encodedURL =intranetUrl+ encodeURI("customer/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=");
var params = 'manish|^test1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$';
$.post(encodedURL,  params,
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });

}
```

It works perfectly on android and blackberry6. But on blackberry5 it doesnot work. I had read that it is shorthand Ajax function and ajax is not supported in blackberry5. Then If I want to send data to server in  blackberry5 then how to do this?

I know in post method we pass parameter in key/value pair. In Rsst client tool if I select method as POst and In URL I give URL as: "http://mySitecustomer/Ri_logon5.asp?requestString=" and in body pass paramter as manish|^test1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$  thrn it gives me proper result. And if I remove requestString= from URL and append it to body parameter then it not give me correct result.

Comment: @jrummell when I run on blackbery5 then alert containing result is not displayed but if I run it on version6 then result is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

## #1:

Those are **not** legal post params.

## #2:

Your page is probably **not** returning `200`

---

Change your code like so (and it just might work ^_^):

```
var encodedURL = intranetUrl + "customer/Ri_logon5.asp";
var params = 'requestString=manish|^test1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$';
$.post(encodedURL,  params,
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });
```

---

Also -- you are not using all of your local variables. If you are not using them, there is **no point** in creating them!

Comment: but on android and blackberry6 simulator I got result in alert.

Comment: @PramodD your post **was not correct at all**! I am surprised it worked on _any_ browser!

Answer (score 0):

Using `XMLHttpRequest`, I am able to post parameters to URLs with:

```
function sendText(txt)
        {

            var internetUrl="http://myURL/";
            var url =internetUrl+ encodeURI("customer/Ri_logon.asp?requestString=");
            var parameters = 'manish|^test1234|^|^X|^11111985|^1.0|^|$';
            alert(url);
            alert(parameters);
            txt = parameters;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.onload = function(e) {
              if (this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
                alert(this.responseText);
              }
              alert("!!!"+this.status);
            };

            xhr.send(txt);
          }

        </script>
```

The code above runs on Android, Blackberry 5 and onwards, and Symbian.